# How can I avoid having to rely on an object of another class to make the methods in a different class work?

Tags: java, object

Maybe the title was confusing, so here's a snippet of what I'm trying to avoid:

```
public class Generator{ 
private static GUI userInterface;
public static boolean specialValidator(String specialEntryText)
{
    if(entryValidator(specialEntryText))
    {
        int specialChars = Integer.parseInt(specialEntryText);
        int maxPossible = Integer.parseInt(userInterface.getLength())-3;
        if(specialChars < 1 || specialChars > maxPossible)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    userInterface = new GUI();
 }
}
```

My program runs and functions as intended (keep in mind there is more to it than this), but I don't know if what I've done here is considered bad practice or what the downsides of doing it this way are. If my `main` method was not in the `Generator` class, this would not work, which seems like a problem to me.

Also, is there a specific name for what I did here, too?

Comment: Why does `specialValidator` need access to `userInterface.getLength`?  Why can't you pass in the value of `maxPossible` as parameter to the method?  Is there a name for what you doing?  I'd put forward "tight coupling".  I'd also question the whole concept of needing `private static GUI userInterface;` in `Generator` at all - seems, limiting, as you've discovered

Comment: In general, the best practice is not to have a static `GUI` object like this, but to pass the `GUI` object to every object that needs it -- often through dependency injection.

Comment: @MadProgrammer For context, this program is a random password generator with a GUI. The user can enter the length of their password and the amount of each type of character (letters, numbers, symbols) to be included in the password. The `specialValidator` method needs to access the `getLength` method to determine how much room is available in the password for special characters as well as the other types. I can't pass `maxPossible` to `getLength` since it's a getter method and doesn't take any arguments. Also, tight coupling definitely seems like the right word for this, thank you!

Comment: @numb31 This is my point - `specialValidator` doesn't need to "access" anything, it needs all the information passed to it - this then makes it a self contained unit of work and "decouples" it

Comment: @MadProgrammer My mistake, I misunderstood you completely. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things jump out at me.

There seems to be a dependency on `GUI` in `specialValidator` which is producing a "tight coupling" - you can't use the method without `GUI`.

This doesn't seem to make sense to me.  You want to focus on reducing this coupling/dependency by passing all the required information into the method directly, for example...

```
public class Generator {

    public static boolean specialValidator(String specialEntryText, int length) {
        if (entryValidator(specialEntryText)) {
            int specialChars = Integer.parseInt(specialEntryText);
            // Any resason we're not using the specialEntryText length?
            int maxPossible = length - 3;
            if (specialChars < 1 || specialChars > maxPossible) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now `specialValidator` doesn't care "how" the information is generated, only that the information is made available to it.  This "decouples" the method and makes it more independent, meaning you can call it any way you like (it also supports "dependence injection" making it more testable )

And now you can call it anyway you like, for example...

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generator.specialValidator("some text", 8);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Just to clarify, `specialEntryText` refers to the text entered inside a textbox on the GUI, and it must always be an integer (which the `entryValidator` method takes care of), since it is used to determine how many special characters are to be included in the password. The actual length of the text entered in the textbox doesn't matter, it just needs to be an integer that isn't so large that it leaves no room for the other types of characters or is larger than the password length. I probably should have named `specialEntryText` something different.

Answer (score 1):

The main method is the entry point of the program, and it needs to be in a class.  It does not need to be in the `Generator` class.

As long as there is access to the class that you want to use, you can call it from another class.  In you case it is `public` so it should be OK.

If it is in another class it could be something like

```
package yourPackage;

public class Main {
    
     public static void main (String[] args) {
    
         Generator gen = new Generator ();
         //
         gen.specialValidator(..);
    }
}
```